# Provision SharePoint Online site with an approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-functions, logic-app

I have a requirement in that whenever an item is added to a pre-existing SharePoint list, a number of things need to occur.

1. A site needs to be created with some customisation
2. One library in the site requires a multi-stage approval workflow.
   This will need to be a repeatable process.

It is possible for a Power Automate wf to trigger when an item is created in the list, which can create a site. The wf can also trigger Azure Automation which can add the customisation. (PowerShell)

How is it possible to create an approval workflow that is reusable and how can be linked to the sites Library.
There may be 200+ sites that get created over time, so it will not be possible to create 200+ workflows manually, it needs to be a single workflow then can be re-used.
I was thinking of LogicApps, does this have the capability ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the OOB "Sign off" Approval workflow. You can deploy it in a few clicks and it's already flexible enough.

Deploying 200 separate flows is going to be a challenge. I would not even go this route.

One suggested workaround that is more scalable is to create a Logic App or an Azure Function that is triggered [via a webhook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks). You will have to register 200 web hook subscriptions. One for each SharePoint list. You will also have to make sure to renew these subscriptions every 180 days (or more often).

Comment: The OOB "Sign Off" is a bit basic and does not allow for multi-stage.

I think the problem with logic apps is that it requires a fixed sharepoint address and not dynamic, so will end up creating 200+ logic apps. Is this true?

Comment: `I think the problem with logic apps is that it requires a fixed sharepoint address and not dynamic`. Logic App has an HTTP trigger which is static. But you can pass additional URL parameters to it. When you register each of your 200 webhooks for each SharePoint list, they will all point to the same HTTP Trigger URL for your Logic App.

Comment: Thanks. To trigger the LogicApp, I think I will need a button against library which should be possible through spfx. When pressed a form appears to collect approvers' names, then Logic App gets the trigger. (Unless there is an easier option)
However, I can't find any documentation on how to pass the Site URL as a parameter into the logic app and then for the Logic App to run it this context. Do you know of any ?

Comment: `I can't find any documentation on how to pass the Site URL as a parameter into the logic app and then for the Logic App to run it this context` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028620/how-to-get-query-parameters-in-a-logic-app/51058306#51058306